# table1.total + table2.point = how?

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

"SELECT * FROM players INNER JOIN " . $v["name"] . " ON players.team_id = " . $v["name"] . ".team_id";

sorry for bad english

i want to + two tables ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store data in single table and fetch `names` and `score/whatever_it_is` like this

```
SELECT name, score FROM players UNION SELECT "Total" AS name, SUM(score) FROM players
```